# Парсинг динамической страницы (script) на Python

Tags: python, xpath

Имею сайт-[цель](https://www.biz-cen.ru).Пытаюсь получить элемент ul с id = 'bObjDataList'.

Мой запрос

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36'}
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
tree = LH.document_fromstring(result.content)
links = tree.xpath('//*[@id="bObjDataList"]')
```

В итоге получаю `[<Element li at 0x3878f98>]` и не могу распарсить дальше.
Запрос должен выдать список элементов li но я не могу дальше их парсить, просто не понимаю.

Мне нужно получить ссылки из тега по XPATH адресу `//*[@id="bcs254"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/a`, с разными id в начале запроса.
Подскажите, как лучше сделать запрос?

Comment: А что за `LH`? Это какой модуль? `lxml`? А как связаны элементы `#bObjDataList` и `//*[@id="bcs254"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/a`?

Comment: LH это import lxml.html as LH.Элемент ul с id = 'bObjDataList' содержит элементы li с [@id="bcs254"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/a

Comment: А можете в самом вопросе предоставить кусок html, из которого хотите вытащить ссылки? Не нужно всю страницу, только конкретный участок. Пока ваш вопрос непонятный и бесполезный для данного сообщества, т.к. в вопросах нужно предоставлять [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :)

Comment: Кст, а сами данные, что вы хотите парсить, они подгружаются с страницы через ajax? Меня к этой мысли название вопроса приводит

Comment: Я не привёл саму страницу вследствие её размера.Там тег ul держит в себе группу с тегами li - для каждого такого тега будет своя обработка.Скрипт сайта вывод на главную список из доступного.К слову, там есть кнопка "загрузить ещё" - видимо подгрузка реализована через Ajax, но в других местах его нет.

Comment: `"Я не привёл саму страницу вследствие её размера."` я поэтому и написал `Не нужно всю страницу, только конкретный участок.`. Вопросы должны быть самодостаточными, т.е. желательно чтобы все, что нужно было, было в вопросе. А пока у меня нет доступа к вашему сайту (корпоративная прокси), поэтому, не имея примера данных для парсинга, помочь не смогу

Answer (score 1):

Вместо того, чтобы запрашивать каждый элемент по `id`, вы можете вытянуть все `<li>` из `<ul id="bObjDataList">`:

```
from lxml import html
import requests


url = 'https://www.biz-cen.ru/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36'}

r  = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

tree = html.fromstring(r.content)

links = tree.xpath('//*[@id="bObjDataList"]/li/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/a/@href')
```

---

```
['/pgsk/',
 '/ofis-m-malevich/',
 '/marvel/',
 '/mitrofanievskoe2/',
 '/ligovskiy50/',
 '/himicheskiy/',
 '/sennaya_4/',
 '/oktyabrskaya104k2/',
 '/aprioiry/',
 '/oktyabrskaya_n_10/',
 '/vzlet/',
 '/nrk/',
 '/partner1/',
 '/shagal/',
 '/ligovskiy50k14/',
 '/moskovskoe_179/',
 '/severnaya_14/',
 '/tempo 2/',
 '/moskovskiy103/',
 '/m-1_arena/']
```

Новые данные подгружаются через AJAX, поэтому для их получения вам возможно нужно будет делать `POST` запросы с определенным набором параметров к `https://www.biz-cen.ru/load/` В инструментах разработчика в браузере вы можете увидеть эти запросы. В хроме это вкладка Network > XHR.

Другой вариант это использовать автоматизацию браузера, например Selenium webdriver. Он будет открываться и жать нужные кнопки для подгрузки данных. После этого, с помощью того же Xpath, вытяните все ссылки.

Comment: Делая запросы к /load/ , скрипт почему-то не видит новый контент.При этом запрос сделан под копирку из XHR панели браузера